# Selenium selector for parent of nodes with specific text

Tags: css, selenium, protractor

Let's say I have 100 elements like this on my page

```
<div class="fc-event-inner">
  <span class="fc-event-time">4p</span>
  <span class="fc-event-title">Singles</span>
</div>
```

How can I select the `div` by contents of both of its children with Selenium / WebDriverJS / Protractor?

None of the labels is unique, but the pair is. So there may be other items with "4p" in the first span or "Singles" in the second. I want to only include those where both values match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are basing this on text, you'd have no choice but using an XPath locator.

This would be what you are looking for (providing you don't have too much nested stuff going on):

```
//div[.//span[text()='4p'] and .//span[text()='Singles']]
```

Which means, get the `div` that has a *child* (at *any* level) span that has it's `text` *exactly* `equal` to `4p` and has a *child* (at *any* level) span that has it's `text` *exactly* `equal` to `Singles`.